# Haskell how can I show function result

Tags: haskell

I have a question that asks me find 'quadratic equation' and `show` result and add number of the roots

example:

```
Main> quadratric 2 2 2
2x^2 + 2x + 2 = 0
Has no real roots.

Main> quadratic 2 5 2
2x^2 + 5x + 2 = 0
Has two real roots:
-2.0 and -0.5
```

So this is quadratic equation:

```
quadraticprob a b c
       | root < 0  = error "Has no real roots"
       | root == 0 = [-b/(2*a)]
       | root > 0  = [-b/(2*a) + sqroot/(2*a),
                             -b/(2*a) - sqroot/(2*a)]
       where
           root = b*b - 4*a*c
           sqroot = sqrt root
```

I can get the result but I should add how many roots they have so I should use one more function that `getLine` and show the result.

I made this but it's totally wrong:

```
readresult :: IO ()
readresult = do
      line <- getLine 
      putStrLn (show (quadraticprob (read line))
```

Can you help me with my mistake please?

Answer (score 2):

Assume you want get 3 integers from standard input call "getLine" function once.

The expression

```
line <- getLine
```

will return a string like (for example)

```
"2 2 2"
```

with spaces between each integer. The first thing need to do is to remove the space and convert it from string to Int type. the ***words*** and ***read*** functions can solve this easily as below:

```
map read (words line)::[Int]
```

However, a integers list cannot pass to your quadratic function directly, it need use ***case*** get elements from list as below

```
case map read (words line)::[Int] of 
     [a, b, c] -> putStrLn $ show $ quadraticprob a b c
```

If you want read real number instead of integers, just change map..::[Int] to ::[Double].

Answer (score 0):

A few hints:

Use a `getLine` for each argument

```
... = do
   astr <- getLine
   bstr <- getLine
   cstr <- getLine
   putStrLn (show (quadraticprob (read astr) (read bstr) (read cstr)))
```

For `quadraticprob`, it's not clear what your goal actually is. Before writing any code, you should start by writing the intended type.

```
quadraticprob :: ?? -> ?? -> ?? -> ??
```

What should that be?

Comment: Hey @chi thank you for message. I forgot to type so indentation is Float ... -> Float. Might my question is not clear. I already can see the quadratic equation roots result with above code but as you can see I should add some additional part like ` "Has two real roots" ` ... I tried if-else and getLine I could not do

Comment: @macintosh That would mean that the result is exactly single float. If that's your type, your function then has only to return a single root.

Comment: hmm, after your point I realised my result is an example like "single root" -> [1.0], "two roots" -> [0.5, 2.0]. I should show this result separate as well like `0.5 and 2.0`

Comment: @macintosh If you want to return those lists, then the result type must be `[Float]` or something similar. Otherwise you could use a custom return type like `data Solutions = None | One Float | Two Float Float` and then `quadraticprob :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Solutions`.